# How can i count the different bankruptcies per week in Rstudio?

Tags: r, count, numbers

I am in the process of charting the number of bankruptcies per week. However, instead of the number of bankruptcies per week it now counts the number of times the week number occurs per week. Does anyone happen to know where I am making the mistake and what the possible solution is?

CODE:

```
    #mergen faillissementen
dataset <- rbind(faillissementen, faillissementen_2, faillissementen_3, faillissementen_4, faillissementen_5, faillissementen_6)

`#datum meegeven
dataset$Datum <- as.Date(as.character(dataset$Datum), format = "%d-%m-%Y")`

    #filter uitgesproken faillissementen
faillissement_uitspraak <- dataset %>% filter(Status == "Faillissement", Uitspraak == "Uitspraak")

    #kolommen verwijderen
faillissementen_opgeschoond_1 = subset(faillissement_uitspraak, select = -c(X,...1, KVK, Plaats, Sbi, Activiteit, Uitspraak, Status, Naam) )

    #aantal faillissementen per datum
aantal_faillissementen <-ddply(faillissementen_opgeschoond_1,.(Datum),nrow)



    #range aangeven van onderzoek
aantal_faillissementen_gegroepeerd <- aantal_faillissementen[(aantal_faillissementen$Datum> "2017-01-01" & aantal_faillissementen$Datum < "2020-09-28"),]

    #aantallen per week benoemen
aantallen_faillissementen_per_week <- aantal_faillissementen_gegroepeerd %>% 
  mutate(week = cut.Date(Datum, breaks = "1 week", labels = FALSE)) %>% 
  arrange(Datum)


    #bankrucpties per week
aantal_faillissementen_per_week_1 <-ddply(aantallen_faillissementen_per_week,.(week),nrow)
```

Comment: Can you please share a reproducible example? A small set of sample input (10 rows is plenty, `dput()` is a nice way to share copy/pasteable data, e.g., `dput(dataset[1:10, ])`).

Comment: Also, please remove the code that is unrelated to the issue. Presumably your `dataset <- rbind(faillissementen, faillissementen_2, ...` line works fine, and since we don't have the inputs `faillissementen`, `faillissementen_2`, ..., it is just a distraction. Similarly with your date conversion, subsetting, removing columns... not relevant. Share with use the data when it is ready to be counted, and we will help you count.